# Problem when drawing on a Panel in Winform

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In event handler of Form Load, I have the following code

```
    Panel pHText = new Panel();
    Font myFont = new Font("Arial", 14);
    pHText.Location=new Point(10,10);
    pHText.Size=new Size(200,200);
    pHText.BackColor = Color.White;
    Graphics g = pHText.CreateGraphics();
    g.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Black), 0, 0, 10, 10);
    g.DrawString("text", myFont, Brushes.Blue, 10, 10);
    Controls.Add(pHText);
```

The white Panel is shown in the form, but those drawing of line and string are not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this code will go in your form load event

```
Panel pHText = new Panel();
pHText.Name = "ctrId"; //specify control name, to access it in other parts of your code
pHText.Location = new Point(10, 10);
pHText.Size = new Size(200, 200);
pHText.BackColor = Color.White;
pHText.Paint += paintingUrCtr;//adding onpaint event
Controls.Add(pHText)
```

add paint event named `paintingUrCtr`.

```
private void paintingUrCtr(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
        Font myFont = new Font("Arial", 14);
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Black),  0, 0, 10, 10);
        e.Graphics.DrawString("text", myFont, Brushes.Blue, 10, 10);
}
```

Comment: Don't use CreateGraphics, use e.Graphics.  Ur is an ancient city in Iraq.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Except that I used `Graphics g = e.Graphics;`,same as Hans mentioned.

Comment: @Hans Passant edited... as for Ur (taking it as a joke, however...) [definition of ur](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=ur) :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to draw on panel in [OnPaint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onpaint%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) event. You cant see your drawing because after components refresh they are redrawed - but you dont.

Answer (score 1):

FormLoad is the wrong place to draw on graphics.
Try to use OnPaint method overload and e.Graphics inside.

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
   // If there is an image and it has a location, 
   // paint it when the Form is repainted.
   base.OnPaint(e);
   if(this.picture != null && this.pictureLocation != Point.Empty)
   {
      e.Graphics.DrawImage(this.picture, this.pictureLocation);
   }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work, the code only runs when the form repaints, not the panel.  The area of the form window that's covered by controls is clipped.